# How do I mount a virtual filesystem in a folder?

Tags: c, windows, virtualfilesystem, dokan

I implemented a virtual filesystem using Dokan. I tried to set the drive letter to C but it errors every time. I was wondering if there is a different virtual filesystem which will allow me to do that or if there is a way of fixing it. Is there some windows api call which will allow me to remount the filesystem in a folder?

Thanks!!!

EDIT: The windows manager does not list the virtual drive, so I cannot mount it through the usual Windows interface. Also, I tried to change the drive name through the property interface and it wouldnt let me do that either.

Comment: I generally ask hard questions, but its the opposite. The C drive is in use and I want to mount the filesystem to a folder on that drive

Comment: Windows since 2000 allows to mount storage devices as folders, without a letter. Does Drive Manager show your virtual device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **MS-DOS [SUBST](http://www.computerhope.com/substhlp.htm) Command** allows you to assign to a drive letter the content of a file system folder:

```
subst z: c:\MyFolder
```

Comment: Close, but what I want is the opposite. I have a virtual drive which I want to make a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use DoaknMountPoint to create a mount point in a existing C drive. Firat make sure Dokan.dll has that API supported.
Drive can be mounted from D thru Z.
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Dokan doesn't create a disk device, that's why you can't see it in device manager or mount it to a folder. In opposite, our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) supports all of this.